# Can fire be made stationary?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am attempting to render an animation where the camera rotates around an object that is engulfed in flames. My goal is to have the camera rotate but for the flames to be immobile throughout.

Is this possible? I have seen tutorials where the flames are made to slow down, but none where they are motionless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as you don't need the smoke to start animating again after it has stopped you can set the start and end frame for the bake to before the set animation frames start.

[image: smoke domain settings]

Above I have set the start frame to `-50` and the end frame to `1`.  Once baked, the smoke animation will be done by (and freeze) at frame `1` and stay frozen for the full animation.  (For some reason the end frame can not be set lower than `1`, but the start frame has no such limit.)

[image: animated gif of the stationary fire]

Comment: Thank you, this works much better than the workaround I came up with after posting.

Comment: @PGmath You got there before I did (great answer, as I was going to even give the same exact values). I'm going to modify your answer to include the rendered proof of this setting.

Comment: @RickRiggs  Great, thanks.  (I'm on my tablet which isn't a fan of simulations.)